# How to get closest n rows for specific row in table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `foo` with its primary key `id` and some other columns.
My goal is to find for instance rows with `id=3` and `id=4` and rows with `id=6` and `id=7` for row with `id=5` - in case I would like to find 2 closest previous and next rows.

In case there is only one or no such rows (e.g. for `id=2` there is only previous row) I would like to get only possible ones.

The problem is there can be some rows missing.

Is there a common practice to make such queries?

Comment: So, if available only one previous row, then you need only one next row? (even if  at beginning   you wanted 5 previous and 5 next rows) ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze nope. In that case I need one previous row and 5 next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2
```

followed by

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

You may be able to combine the above into the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution by numbering all the records and fetching those where row number is 2 rows greater or lower than the selected ID.

> ```
> create table foo(id int);
> insert into foo values (1),(2),(4),(6),(7),(8),(11),(12);
> ```

> ```
> -- using ID = 6
>
> with rnum as
> (
>     select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn
>     from foo
> )
> select *
> from   rnum
> where  rn >= (select rn from rnum where id = 6) - 2
> and    rn <= (select rn from rnum where id = 6) + 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | rn
> -: | -:
>  2 |  2
>  4 |  3
>  6 |  4
>  7 |  5
>  8 |  6
> ```

> ```
> -- using ID = 2
>
> with rnum as
> (
>     select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn
>     from foo
> )
> select *
> from   rnum
> where  rn >= (select rn from rnum where id = 2) - 2
> and    rn <= (select rn from rnum where id = 2) + 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | rn
> -: | -:
>  1 |  1
>  2 |  2
>  4 |  3
>  6 |  4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cbf9e2abff3c19929aacf40dafe862ed)*

Answer (score 0):

I think this would fit your description.

```
Select * from table where id between @n-2 and @n+2 and id <> @n
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is this:

```
with your_table(id) as(
    select 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 4 union all
    select 5 union all
    select 10 union all
    select 11 union all
    select 12 union all
    select 13 union all
    select 14  
)

select * from (
    (select * from your_table where id <= 10 order by id desc limit 3+1)
    union all
    (select * from your_table where id > 10 order by id limit 3)
) t
order by id
```

(Here `10` is start point and `3` is `n` rows you want)